# Adding collections in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

There's clearly something I'm misunderstanding about the following query and any enlightenment would be appreciated.

I had been reading up on the UNIONS and collections in cypher - specifically the following page:
https://neo4j.com/blog/cypher-union-query-using-collect-clause/

So I decided to attempt something similar to return if a profile had a permission (I think the node graph is fairly obvious here but can provide some creates if needed).

```
Match (p:Profile)-[:authorised]->(p1:Permission)
where p.username = 'user1'
with collect(p1) as directPerms
Match (p:Profile)-[:has_role]->(:Role)-[:authorised]->(p2:Permission)
  where p.username = 'user1'
with directPerms + collect(p2) as plusRolePerms
Match (p:Profile)-[:member_of]->(:Group)-[:authorised]->(p3:Permission)
  where p.username = 'user1'
with plusRolePerms + collect(p3) as allPerms
RETURN ANY(perm IN allPerms WHERE perm.id = 'ACCESS') as hasPermission
```

Here's where I'm stuck. Say the user does have the 'ACCESS' permission as a direct or role permission but has 0 group permissions then the query doesn't return anything at all!

I'm assuming I'm misunderstanding adding lists together. I'm also aware I'm not using UNWIND as outlined on the webpage, however, I'm not doing any post query sorting/manipulation so assume I don't need to...?

Any help would be appreciated :D

*EDIT*

I've accepted an answer to this because it solves part of the question. My particular favourite solution was:

```
MATCH (p:Profile {username: 'user1'}), (a:Permission {id: 'ACCESS'})
RETURN
  (p)-[:authorised]->(a) OR
  (p)-[:has_role]->(:Role)-[:authorised]->(a) OR
  (p)-[:member_of]->(:Group)-[:authorised]->(a)
  AS hasPermission
```

as it retains clarity (although @InverseFalcon had a shorter possibly faster solution too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a succinct Cypher query that is also more efficient (since it does not bother to maintain a growing collection). It also has the potential to generate an execution plan that will finish the query as soon as an `ACCESS` id value is found (but the current Cypher planners *may* not generate such a plan yet).

```
MATCH (p:Profile {username: 'user1'})
RETURN
  (p)-[:authorised]->(:Permission {id: 'ACCESS'}) OR
  (p)-[:has_role]->(:Role)-[:authorised]->(:Permission {id: 'ACCESS'}) OR
  (p)-[:member_of]->(:Group)-[:authorised]->(:Permission {id: 'ACCESS'})
  AS hasPermission;
```

[EDIT]

Or, even better, if there is only a single `Permission` node with the `ACCESS` id:

```
MATCH (p:Profile {username: 'user1'}), (a:Permission {id: 'ACCESS'})
RETURN
  (p)-[:authorised]->(a) OR
  (p)-[:has_role]->(:Role)-[:authorised]->(a) OR
  (p)-[:member_of]->(:Group)-[:authorised]->(a)
  AS hasPermission;
```

Or, as @InverseFalcon suggested, you could do the following (I assume, again, that there is only a single `Permission` node with the `ACCESS` id). This generates the simplest execution plan, but is harder to understand:

```
MATCH (p:Profile {username: 'user1'}), (a:Permission {id: 'ACCESS'})
RETURN (p)-[:has_role|member_of*0..1]-()-[:authorised]->(a) AS hasPermission;
```

Comment: We might be able to get it down a bit smaller. Give this a try for the return: `RETURN
  (p)-[:has_role|member_of*0..1]-()-[:authorised]->(:Permission {id: 'ACCESS'}) AS hasPermission`

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. Much appreciated. I've updated the question to reflect my favourite answer. There is still one aspect of my original question that I'm keen to get my head around - why were the lists in the original example returned as nil if one of the later Matches returned nil. Please understand, I'm keen to get better at Cypher and not trying to be difficult - simply confused.

Comment: Any `MATCH` (that is not an `OPTIONAL MATCH`) that fails to match will cause the entire query to fail.

Comment: Aha! Thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

If you make all of the permission matches `OPTIONAL MATCH` and separate out the user match then you will only never return a result in the case the user does not exist. As a bonus, you only need to find the user node once instead of three times.

```
MATCH (p:Profile)
WHERE p.username = 'user1'
WITH p
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:authorised]->(p1:Permission)
WITH p, collect(p1) as directPerms
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:has_role]->(:Role)-[:authorised]->(p2:Permission)
WITH p, directPerms + collect(p2) as plusRolePerms
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:member_of]->(:Group)-[:authorised]->(p3:Permission)
WITH p, plusRolePerms + collect(p3) as allPerms
RETURN ANY(perm IN allPerms WHERE perm.id = 'ACCESS') as hasPermission
```